# Query to delete where id is other than multiple values?

Tags: sql

How would I make a query to  delete the column where id is other than multiple values?

I tried

```
DELETE FROM `Player` WHERE `Player`.`Squad` != 3,
4,
8,
9,
10,
11,
21, 
31,
36,
43,
64,
65,
66,
71,
74,
103,
105,
154,
171,
190;
```

Thanks

Comment: use NOT IN clause as described by SRIRAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` as below:

```
 DELETE FROM Player WHERE Player.Squad NOT IN ( 3, 4, 8,9,10,11,21, 31,36,43,
                                            64,65,66,71,74,103,105,154,171,190);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like

```
Delete from player where player.squad not in (3,4,8,9,10,...)
```

Answer (score 2):

DELETE FROM Player WHERE Squad NOT IN ( 3, 4, 8,9..........);
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-foreign-keys.html please refer dz link for more info

Answer (score 1):

you can use **NOT IN**

```
DELETE FROM `Player` WHERE `Player`.`Squad` not in (3,4,8,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` sql is caseinsensitive either we can use  smalls or caps no problem.

```
DELETE FROM Player WHERE Squad NOT IN ( 3, 4, 8,9,10,11,21, 31,36,43,
                                        64,65,66,71,74,103,105,154,171,190);
```

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answer.